# How can I get the best sound quality from my Zoom H1?

Tags: noise, zoom

I just bought a Zoom H1 to do things like walking interviews, conversations and sound effects from streets. Having tested it out so far, and from what I've read, there is quite a lot of noise that seems to come from handling the case and I'm starting to question whether this is the right purchase and if it's actually any better quality than making recordings on my iPhone.

Are there things I can do to mitigate these factors and get clear recordings out of the H1 or do I need to upgrade to a more expensive model? I realise that for some cases I can just put it down somewhere, but I explicitly bought it for being out and about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom, buy a little camera tripod for a few quid, screw it into the threaded socket in the bottom of the H1 and use it as a handle. This avoids handling the casing when recording.

To help prevent wind interference when out and about, I just use some really cheap furry material and lay it over the whole recorder, because wind affects the casing as well as the mics.